# How to get max value from second column & min value from third column in CSV file with no row header in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How to get the max value from the second column and min value from the third column in CSV file with no row headers as per the screenshot of DataFrame through defining a function?

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
def minmaxvalue(filename):
    # some code
      
minmaxvalue("my_data.cvs")
```

How to get the max&min value between the defining function?

```
i   a   b
1   33  99
2   35  100
3   37  101
4   39  102
5   41  103
6   43  104
7   45  105
8   47  106
9   49  107
10  51  108
11  53  109
12  55  110
13  57  111
14  59  112
15  61  113
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
def minmaxvalue(filename):
    # reading from file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=['a', 'b'])
    # returning max and min
    return df['a'].max(), df['b'].min()
      
minmaxvalue("my_data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is this:

```
def minmaxvalue(filename):
    minim = filename['a'][0]
    maxim = filename['b'][0]
    for i in range(0, len(filename)):
        if minim > filename['a'][i]:
            minim = filename['a'][i]
        if maxim < filename['b'][i]:
            maxim = filename['b'][i]
        
    return minim, maxim
```